# Is there a simple way to print each element of an array?

Tags: arrays, printing, f#

```
let x=[|15..20|]
let y=Array.map f x
printf "%O" y
```

Well, I got a type information.

Is there any way to print each element of "y" with delimiter of ",", while not having to use a for loop?

Comment: homework@stackexchange?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use `String.Join` in the `System` namespace or F# 'native':

```
let x = [| 15 .. 20 |]

printfn "%s" (System.String.Join(",", x))

x |> Seq.map string |> String.concat "," |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: Well, I really like this pipe-line style of programming, the steps are so clear. Just like powershell!

Answer (score 2):

Using `String.concat` to concatenate the string with a separator is probably the best option in this case (because you do not want to have the separator at the end).

However, if you just wanted to print all elements, you can also use `Array.iter`:

```
let nums= [|15..20|]
Array.iter (fun x -> printfn "%O" x) nums    // Using function call
nums |> Array.iter (fun x -> printfn "%O" x) // Using the pipe
```

Adding the separators in this case is harder, but possible using `iteri`:

```
nums |> Array.iteri (fun i x ->
  if i <> 0 then printf ", "
  printf "%O" x)
```

Comment: Note, that in the first case, the verbose `fun x ->` is not needed: ```Array.iter (printfn "%O") nums``` and ```nums |> Array.iter (printfn "%O")```

Answer (score 1):

This won't print the entire array if it is large; I think it prints only the first 100 elements.  Still, I suspect this is what you're after:

```
printfn "%A" y
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array of items is large and you do not want to generate a large string, another option is to generate a interleaved sequence and skip the first item. The following code works assuming the array has at least one element.

One advantage of this approach is that it cleanly separates the act of interleaving  the items and that of printing. It also eliminates having to do a check for the first item on every iteration.

```
let items = [| 15 .. 20|]

let strInterleaved delimiter items = 
    items 
    |> Seq.collect (fun item -> seq { yield delimiter; yield item}) 
    |> Seq.skip(1)

items
|>  Seq.map string
|>  strInterleaved "," 
|>  Seq.iter (printf "%s")
```